# WSO2 APIM-Analytic service (version:2.6.0) is not able to send the alert emails

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In order to test this function, I chosed **Abnormal Request Count** option, which is in Alert Management menu of Api Store, and added a restful api. Then I called this api for many times by Postman.

The carbon.log, which is in `<API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/wso2/worker/logs`, recorded the following error message:

```
[2020-10-19 11:03:36,094] ERROR {org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.Sink} - Error on 'APIM_ALERT_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION'. Dropping event at Sink 'email' at 'EmailNotificationStream' as its still trying to reconnect!, events dropped '<strong>Message:</strong>A request from a new IP (10.9.16.77) detected by user:admin@carbon.super using application:devMap owned by admin@carbon.super. <br><br> <strong>Type:</strong>UnusualIPAccess <br><br> <strong>AlertTimestamp:</strong>2020-10-19 11:03:35'
[2020-10-19 11:06:10,307] ERROR {org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.Sink} - Error on 'APIM_ALERT_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION'. Dropping event at Sink 'email' at 'EmailNotificationStream' as its still trying to reconnect!, events dropped '<strong>Message:</strong>Abnormal request count detected during last minute using application devMap owned by admin@carbon.super for api :全球风向查询, abnormal request count:9. <br><br> <strong>Type:</strong>AbnormalRequestsPerMin <br><br> <strong>AlertTimestamp:</strong>2020-10-19 11:06:10'
```

About detailed configuration, I referred the following links:

1. Configuring Alerts:
   *https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Alerts#ConfiguringAlerts-ConfiguringalertsviatheStore*
2. Enabling Notifications:
   *https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Enabling+Notifications*

According to these documents, I did the following things:

1.Open the <API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/conf/worker/deployment.yaml file to configure the sender email address. The sample code is shown below:

```
siddhi:
  extensions:
...
    -
      extension:
        name: email
        namespace: sink
        properties:
          username: abcd@163.com
          address: abcd@163.com
          password: xxxx
...
```

2.Go to the <API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/resources/apim-analytics/ directory. Copy the APIM_ALERT_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION.siddhi file and paste it in the <API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/wso2/worker/deployment/siddhi-files directory.

3.Set the email server configurations in the <API-M_HOME>/repository/conf/output-event-adapters.xml file under the  section.

```
<adapterConfig type="email">
       <!-- Comment mail.smtp.user and mail.smtp.password properties to support connecting SMTP servers which use trust
       based authentication rather username/password authentication -->
       <property key="mail.smtp.from">abcd@163.com</property>
       <property key="mail.smtp.user">abcd</property>
       <property key="mail.smtp.password">xxxx</property>
       <property key="mail.smtp.host">smtp.163.com</property>
       <property key="mail.smtp.port">25</property>
       <property key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</property>
       <property key="mail.smtp.auth">true</property>
       <!-- Thread Pool Related Properties -->
       <property key="minThread">8</property>
       <property key="maxThread">100</property>
       <property key="keepAliveTimeInMillis">20000</property>
       <property key="jobQueueSize">10000</property>
   </adapterConfig>
```

4.Log in to the Management Console and click Main > Resource > Browse. Browse to the /_system/config/apimgt/applicationdata/tenant-conf.json file and click Edit as Text.Set the NotificationsEnabled property to true as shown below:

```
"NotificationsEnabled":"true",
  "Notifications":[{
    "Type":"new_api_version",
    "Notifiers" :[{
      "Class":"org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.notification.NewAPIVersionEmailNotifier",
      "ClaimsRetrieverImplClass":"org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever",
      "Title": "Version $2 of $1 Released",
      "Template": " <html> <body> <h3 style=\"color:Black;\">We’re happy to announce the arrival of the next major version $2 of $1 API which is now available in Our API Store.</h3><a href=\"https://localhost:9443/store\">Click here to Visit WSO2 API Store</a></body></html>"
 
    }]
  }
  ]
```

I've also checked APIM_ALERT_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION.siddhi:

```
@App:name("APIM_ALERT_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION")
@App:description('Send email to all the subscribers of a particular alert') 

@source(type="inMemory", topic="APIM_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION", @map(type='passThrough'))
define stream EmailAlertStream (
    type    string, 
    message string, 
    alertTimestamp  string, 
    emails  string);

@sink(type='email', content.type="text/html", @map(type ='text', @payload('<strong>Message:</strong>{{message}} <br><br> <strong>Type:</strong>{{type}} <br><br> <strong>AlertTimestamp:</strong>{{alertTimestamp}}')),subject='Alerts from WSO2 APIM Analytics',to='{{emails}}')
define stream EmailNotificationStream (
    type    string,
    message string,
    alertTimestamp  string,
    emails  string);

from EmailAlertStream
select *
insert into EmailNotificationStream;
```

As you can see, there is nothing special.

Have I missed anything to do? I don't know what the problem is, please help me.

Comment: your requirement to enable, APIM email notification or analytics alert?

Comment: @ruks: Both of them are what I want. 
By reading the WSO2 documentation, I knew that the e-mail functions have already been provided by APIM notification and analytics alert.

Answer (score 0):

As per the exceptions you received. Looks like there are issues with connecting to the SMTP server. Can you please check the configurations and check there are any restrictions to use your email.
ex: in Gmail, you have to enable 'untrusted applications' to access Gmail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I'm going to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason of this problem.
By reading the source code (EmailSink.java), I know the information of SMTP Server should be configured in APIM_ALERT_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION.siddhi, otherwise the analytic server is going to use smtp.gmail.com by default.